# как передавать в localStorage 3 последних операции калькулятора

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, localstorage

Хочу чтобы в `localStorage` попадало 3 последних операции, подскажите плс  как правильно сделать

```js
////////////////take  buttons value////////////////////////
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number'),
    operations = document.querySelectorAll('.operator'),
    out = document.getElementById('cancel'),
    disp = document.getElementById('display'),
    memoryCurrentNumber = 0,
    memoryNewNumber = false,
    memoryPendingOperation = '';
//////////////////////////////////////take  numbers content///////////////
for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    let number = numbers[i];
    number.addEventListener('click', e  =>{
        numberPress(e.target.textContent);
        window.localStorage.setItem('key','number');
    });

}
//////////////////////////////////////take  number operators content///////////////
for(let i=0; i<operations.length; i++) {
    let operationBtn = operations[i];
    operationBtn.addEventListener('click', e =>{
        operation(e.target.textContent);
        window.localStorage.setItem('key','operator');
    });

}
///////////////////////////button cancel, clear all field///////////////////
out.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    disp.value = '0';
    memoryNewNumber = true;
    memoryCurrentNumber = 0;
    memoryPendingOperation = '';
});

////////////////////////////////////write numbers  and fix  position zero//////////////////
let numberPress =  (number) => {
    if(memoryNewNumber) {
        disp.value = number;
        memoryNewNumber = false;
    }else {
        if(disp.value === '0') {
            disp.value = number;
        }else {
            disp.value += number;
        }
    }
    window.localStorage.getItem("key");
};
//////////////////////general calc operations////////////////////////
let operation =  (operation) => {
 let localOperationMemory = disp.value;

    if (memoryNewNumber && memoryPendingOperation !== '=') { /////////////// make '=' res
    disp.value = memoryCurrentNumber;

    }else {
        memoryNewNumber = true;
        if(memoryPendingOperation === '+') {
            memoryCurrentNumber += parseFloat(localOperationMemory);


        } else if(memoryPendingOperation === '-') {
            memoryCurrentNumber -= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);

        }else if(memoryPendingOperation === '*') {
            memoryCurrentNumber *= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);

        }else if(memoryPendingOperation === '/') {
            memoryCurrentNumber /= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
            if(localOperationMemory == 0) {
                memoryCurrentNumber = 'calculator smart u no :(';
                memoryNewNumber = true;
                memoryPendingOperation = '';
            }
        }
        else {
            memoryCurrentNumber = parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
        }
        disp.value = memoryCurrentNumber;
        memoryPendingOperation = operation;

    }
    window.localStorage.getItem("key");
};
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 calculator">
  <div class="display">
      <input disabled type="text" id="display"  value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="keybord">
      <button class="number">1</button>
      <button class="number">2</button>
      <button class="number">3</button>
      <button class="operator" id="plus">+</button>
      <br>
      <button class="number">4</button>
      <button class="number">5</button>
      <button class="number">6</button>
      <button class="operator">-</button>
      <br>
      <button class="number">7</button>
      <button class="number">8</button>
      <button class="number">9</button>
      <button class="operator" id="multiply">*</button>
      <br>
      <button class="number">0</button>
      <button id="res" class="operator">=</button>
      <button id="cancel">c</button>
      <button class="operator" id="sr">/</button>
  </div>
</div>
```